# How to switch left and right audio devices on elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera

Tags: settings, sound, audio

I have stereo speakers and am looking for a way to swap audio output of the left and right speakers. Is there any programmatic way of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/uzzjd/how_to_swap_audio_channels_in_pulseaudio/c502cyr?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

[image]

Comment: thank you bro. this is work on my TOSHIBA Dynabook with Elementary OS 5.1

Comment: Thank you, too :)) maybe you can upvote the question, too :D